# Remove yaml property and its definition from yaml files in a directory using php or bash

Tags: php, bash

I have many yaml files that have a property definition on multiple lines:

```
  approval_date:
    label: inline
    type: datetime_plain
    weight: 3
    region: content
    settings:
      timezone_override: ''
    third_party_settings: {  }
```

I would like to be able to remove the approval_date and its definition from all yaml files. I tried a simple regex search and replace and it work to an extent but the definition varies across different files. Is there a simpler way to remove the property and its definition wherever it using bash script or something similar?

Comment: In YAML only nodes have properties, and those are either an anchor/alias property or a tag property. What you describe and want to remove is not a YAML property

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what you mean. I just want to remove the entire block defined by approval_date in all yaml files. Pls feel free to edit the question and add the correct termenology

Answer (score 0):

I don't know PHP, but here's a ruby one-liner: read the yaml file into a hash, delete the requested hash key, and emit the new yaml

```
$ cat file.yaml
some stuff:
- a
- b
- c
approval_date:
    label: inline
    type: datetime_plain
    weight: 3
    region: content
    settings:
      timezone_override: ''
    third_party_settings: {  }
more stuff: here
```

```
$ ruby -e '
    require "yaml"
    data = YAML.load(File.read(ARGV.shift))
    data.delete("approval_date")
    puts YAML.dump(data)
' file.yaml
---
some stuff:
- a
- b
- c
more stuff: here
```

Answer (score 0):

Bash by itself will not handle yaml, and I haven't had success with any of the various libraries that are supposed to add half-hearted support for it.

I have, however, had success treating yaml as JSON using [`y2j`](https://github.com/wildducktheories/y2j), which allows your yaml to be parsed using the language of [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

Witness:

```
$ cat x.yml
  keep_me: foo
  approval_date:
    label: inline
    type: datetime_plain
    weight: 3
    region: content
    settings:
      timezone_override: ''
    third_party_settings: {  }
  more_to_keep:
    label: bar
$ yq 'del(.approval_date)' < x.yml
keep_me: foo
more_to_keep:
  label: bar
```

Note that the `yq` command is a link to `y2j.sh`, which is a bash script. The `jq` command can probably be added to your system using the normal package manager for your operating system.

Of course, doing this in PHP alone may be easier.

```
$ php -r '$a=yaml_parse_file("x.yml"); unset($a["approval_date"]); print_r($a);'
Array
(
    [keep_me] => foo
    [more_to_keep] => Array
        (
            [label] => bar
        )

)
```

Or even:

```
$ php -r '$a=yaml_parse_file("x.yml"); unset($a["approval_date"]); print yaml_emit($a);'
---
keep_me: foo
more_to_keep:
  label: bar
...
```